# Why this code add only a single data from an array into a menu table

Tags: arrays, object, joomla, menu

I am able to obtain the `$data` array from a form and I can generate data for each item... But during the binding and storing with jTable object it saves only the latest item why... I am using native JTableMenu class to bind and save by using my own class which is extended by native one. Early trials I used database object to save items with sql syntax but some columns of table remains empty lft and rgt to fill them I used table object but it gives this issue.

The whole code is following:

```
function addcumulative($data){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $component = & JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_dratransport');
    $menus = array();
    $query = array();
    $countries = DraTransportHelperArrays::countries();
    $cities = DraTransportHelperArrays::cities();


    $title = array();
    $alias = array();
    $path  = array();
    $link = array();

    if(empty($data['parent_id']) && $data['parent_id'] == 0){
        $data['parent_id'] = 1;
    }else{
        $parent_id = explode('.',$data['parent_id']);
        $data['parent_id'] = $parent_id[1];
    }

    if(!empty($data['locationQuery'])){ //actually this part will be used
        $loc = ($data['locationQuery'] == 'countries') ? $countries : $cities['Turkey'] ;   

        foreach($loc as $k => $c){
            $query[0] = $data['general'];
            foreach($data as $key => $dat){
                if(!empty($dat) && strpos($key,'Query') !== false){
                    $v = explode('Q',$key);
                    if($v[0] !== 'location'){
                        $query[] = '&'.$v[0].'='.$dat;
                    }else{
                        $query[] = '&'.$dat.'='.$k;
                    }
                }
            }   
            $title[] = $data['viewQuery'].'-'.$k;
            $alias[] = $data['viewQuery'].'-'.$k;
            $path[] = $data['viewQuery'].'-'.$k;                
            $link[] = implode('',$query);
            $query = array();
        }

    }else{
        $query[0] = $data['general'];
        foreach($data as $key => $dat){             
            if(!empty($dat) && strpos($key,'Query') !== false){
                $v = explode('Q',$key);
                $query[] = '&'.$v[0].'='.$dat;
            }
        }
        $link[] = implode('',$query);
    }

    foreach($link as $n => $l){
        $menus[] = array(
                         'menutype'     =>  $data['menutype'],
                         'title'        =>  $title[$n],
                         'alias'        =>  $alias[$n],
                         'path'         =>  $path[$n],
                         'link'         =>  $link[$n],
                         'type'         =>  'component',
                         'published'    =>  1,
                         'parent_id'    =>  $data['parent_id'],
                         'level'        =>  1,
                         'component_id' =>  $component->id,
                         'access'       =>  $data['access'],
                         'params'       =>  $data['params'],
                         'language'     =>  '*'
                    );
    }

    $count = $data['count'] == 0 ? count($loc) : $data['count'];    
    foreach($menus as $menu){
        // Bind the data.
        $table  = $this->getTable();
        $table->bind($menu);                
        $table->store();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you obtaining these values? 

  'parent_id'    =>  $data['parent_id'],
 'level'        =>  1,


 I definitely question hard coding level to 1

Remember that JTableMenu extends JTableNested so it is essential that you handle the nesting correctly, that is where the lft and rgt come from.

Comment: All the values which is relatedt to $data array come form the form which is submited. And the values of menu array like$title array is generated in previouse codes to relate different title with differenet menu item. I lernt that to use lft and rgt I must use JTableMenu which is extendet JTableNested. But I couldnt understant why it adds only one (actually last one) item to db while it is in for statemnt.

Comment: Honestly I almost never see code that uses a for loop in Joomla. WHy don't you look at some of the core code and development documentation?  Most likely if you are processing many items you will want to get an object list and use do over.

Perhaps it would help if you explained exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have 236 country in an array and I want to create menu items which has the country parameter in its link. Buy manually to ad 236 menu manulaly is hard to do so I want to add to database directly by coding. I have three types of category and each shoudl have that manu items seperatly so 3*236 menu ı should make :) To make modules related with each individual country ;)

Comment: Why don't you just use the API to add code though? JTableNested has lots of methods to help you with this and that will keep the nesting straight.

Comment: JTableMenu is already extended from Nested table... I am jsut asking while my code is processing it adds only one entry to the database table even if it is in for loop... why it does not add the 236 entry...

Comment: I know it extends it but you are not using the APIs from it.

Comment: ALso what is it that you are trying to do with the loop when you are already in a foureach?
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/table/nested.php#L708

Comment: I am using for loop to control how items are addet to db if they are added wrong deleting of 236 entry could be hard if code works I will change the for to foreach. But I couldnt understand the mean of using API froum nested. Aren^t store and bind fuunctions in API :S and where the foreach statemen in nested table code :S sorry for my weaknes in programming.

Comment: Okay so where are you importing them from?

Comment: I have an array containing the countries with keys, and I have forms. All the menu items will have same parameterse except the query piece &countries by using foreach... I am able to crate an array containing all the menu items but I couldn add them into db if I use sql statemnt instead of JTABLEMENU it adds all items in for loop.. but JTableMenu adds just the last one.

Comment: I take the code $table  = $this->getTable();   inside the for loop and then it adds all the series to the database both with tablenested and table menu. But altouhgt I assigned the parant_id and level it assigns 0 for both for all the items added. I need to make those values 1. In table nested it takes them from repisotorydate but I don't undrstand what is that. Thansk for your help and reading.

Comment: You should not be doing the insert yourself, you should use the api to do it.

Comment: I couldn't understand meaning of using api yet... I am already using the joomlas own function like table bind and store what is the difference of using api... And I am realy thankfulfor your replys I just want to go further and learn lots of things

Comment: YOu are already binding and storing the data you don't need to do an insert on top of that. The binding and then storing are doing that for you.

Comment: What do you mean with saying insert o top of that... can you explani it by taking the piece of code from above. I have a form and I obtain the parameters with $data array ant to bind each item I create $menus array to bind in for loop :S wher is the mistake in the code... :S can you give the line number or code pice from it where is mistake. Thanks

Comment: I'm still really confused about what you are doing.
If I understand correctly you have in a model something like

$countries = array (England, France, Germany);
And then each country element has an array of the data for the menu item?
Then you are doing 

foreach ($countries as country)
{
 creating the new row of data from the array for that country;
 $this->save();
}

Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are totally right. Let say $countries=array('England','France','Germany'); then I wrote my code in model to generate links in #__menu table. So I write 

foreach($countries as $country){
$link='index.php&option=com_mycomponent&view=members&type=1&countries='.$country;
$table->bind();
$table->save();
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are totally right. Let say $countries=array('England','France','Germany'); then I wrote my code in model to generate links in #__menu table. So I write

```
foreach($countries as $country){
$link='index.php&option=com_mycomponent&view=members&type=1&countries='.$country;
$table->bind();
$table->save();
}
```

I am generating links like this, view and the type values in query comes from the form submitted to make parmaters same for all menus except countries;
and I assign all parametes to manu item and menu items to an array as array item...
to save database the table comes with nested.

$menus->$each menu as $menus array item->menu item parameters

while the table is first created in above code code just adds the last menu item but if I take it insede the foreach it adds all of them but parent_id and level parameters assigned to 0 bye the native code altought I set them as 1

Comment: Do not assign level, just assign parent_id. Level will be created for you based on the parent level+1.  Also you do not need to bind() and save() . Save() is a convenience method that does check(), bind(), store(). 
It looks to me like you are not creating a new row object for each iteration through the foreach, you just keep updating the same row.